# Android - Prevent resize on drag

Tags: android

### Edit: Earlier, I said I saw this behavior only on right bound. My mistake. It happens on right bound as well as bottom bound.

I have a simple test activity that has the following view hierarchy.

```
RelativeLayout
   -- LinearLayout
       --TextView
```

I have implemented drag mechanism on the LinearLayout object. In the OnTouchListener implementation, I adjust leftMargin and topMargin of the object. The idea is to make this object a floating window within the root layout.

This mostly works as expected. However, the problem comes in when I try to move the view partially out of the right bound of the root window. In this case, the view starts resizing. As a result, the text starts wrapping to the next line.

This problem does not seem to occur when I move the view partially out of the left or top bounds. It is only with the right bound and the bottom bound.

I have looked at a few similar messages. Some suggested implementing setClipChidren(false) and setClipToPadding(false). However, this does not have any effect.

Is there anything else that I am missing?

Comment: Is there any kind of right boundary set on the actual XML? IE. if you set alignParentRight="true" that could totally have the same resizing affect you're experiencing

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not using any XML at all. It is just a few simple lines of code - create, set layout params, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the bounds of your parent layout and limit your drag mechanish to these bounds. Here is how I do it:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms=(LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
    //parms.topMargin=0;
    //parms.leftMargin=0;
    RelativeLayout parent=(RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
        {
            parms = (LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        }
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
        {
            if (event.getRawX()>v.getWidth()/2 && event.getRawX()<(parent.getWidth()-v.getWidth()/2) &&
                    event.getRawY()>v.getHeight()/2 && event.getRawY()<(parent.getHeight()-v.getHeight()/2)
                    ) {
                parms.leftMargin=(int) event.getRawX()-v.getWidth()/2;
                parms.topMargin=(int)event.getRawY()-v.getHeight()/2;
                v.setLayoutParams(parms);
            }



        }
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
        {
            //your stuff
        }

}
    return true;
}
```